# Angular changed with typescript input field value empty on submit

Tags: angular, input

I want to update input field by given name or id value with ts method with its id or name given with string.

I try diferent options with update ngModel ngValue but thats not it.

So i have an ipnut field

```
<div class="col-auto">
<input type="text" id="yproduct" name="yproduct" class="form-control"  ngModel required>
</div>
```

And i change its value form service with:

```
this.stockInfoService.caller.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.caller = data
    document.getElementById(this.caller).value = this.codeScan;
  }
);
```

Everything works on html side and the field value shows inside input, but when i submit the form i have empty yproduct value !

```
{yproduct: ''}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `document` object, Angular should be the one handling the DOM. Also, have you tried using either `Template driven forms ` or `Reactive forms`?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : you should never have to call `document.getElementById` in Angular. If you end up manually using `document` at all, you probably have a design flaw.

`[(ngModel)]` enables to do some double data binding between a typescript variable and an `<input>`.

Correct usage is :

**Typescript**

```js
foo = 42
```

**HTML**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="foo">
```

Then, on backend call, you would just have to modify the `foo` value and it would be reflected in the `input`

That being said, your main problem comes from the fact that you want to modify a field that is dynamically chosen by the backend. In order to do that, you can create multiple variables with a big switch case. That is easy, that would work but the code would be messy.

I would rather bind all `<input>` to different attributes of a `data` object :

**TypeScript**

```js
  data = {
    foo: 42,
    bar: 51,
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>Foo : <input id="foo" [(ngModel)]="data.foo" /></div>
<div>Bar: <input id="bar" [(ngModel)]="data.bar" /></div>
```

And on backend call, you just have to modify the right data attribute :

**TypeScript**

```js
  callBackend() {
    this.fakeService().subscribe((resp) => {
      this.data[resp] = this.codeScan;
    })
  }
```

See StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w6gcxy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)